# Does ASP.NET MVC 5 support speech recognition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, speech-recognition

I want to know if ASP.NET MVC 5 supports speech recoginition. I want to code a login system with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.net is a web framework for building websites with HTML, Javascript and CSS, it doesn't even work with sound at all.

However, you can use HTML speech recognition API (works in Chrome only) for speech recognition. You can create required HTML page with ASP.NET and present it to the user. You can learn more about HTML speech recognition API from the following page:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

It is not recommended to use speech recognition for login, it's not very secure.