# How to make authentication using Sound Recognition

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I need to make Login system which use sound as authentication method. Recognize the sound and allow the user to login to the web application?

Comment: try this link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/877208/How-to-implement-voice-recognition-in-Csharp-using

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269101/does-asp-net-mvc-5-support-speech-recognition) and [this article](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/05/using-html5-speech-recognition-and-text-to-speech)

Comment: Great blog: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/05/using-html5-speech-recognition-and-text-to-speech

Comment: Thanks for the links